# Ctypes structure with variable types?

Tags: python, ctypes

I have two very basic structs, with different data types defined.

```
class a(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", c_double),
                ("y", c_double),
                ("z", c_double)]


class b(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", c_float),
                ("y", c_float),
                ("z", c_float)]
```

Is there any way to unify these two structures, or allow variable types? In my code, I have a stream of data that comes in and either of type float32 or float64. I'd like to avoid using a wrapper function that returns a struct, so the final struct can remain defined in global space.

Edit: Tried something like this, no go:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import c_int, c_float, Structure, Union


class a_d(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", c_float),
                ("y", c_float),
                ("z", c_float),
                ("w", c_int)]


class a_f(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", c_int),
                ("y", c_int),
                ("z", c_int),
                ("w", c_float)]                



class a(Union):
    _fields_ = [('ad',a_d),('af',a_f)]


A = a()
A.af.x = 5

print A.ad.x #does not print 5.0 (prints 7.00649232162e-45)
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is `ctypes.Union` to create a data type which can be one type or the other.

Comment: @Michael Butscher - Looked into that and it looks like it should do what I want, though I'm not quite there yet. Any tips/fixes on my updated post?

Comment: Why should it print 5.0? You're allowing both int and float types; then you assign an int, so it should print an int, no? Update with expected outputs.

Comment: Oh, it doesn't even print 5. It prints 7.00649232162e-45. I'm guessing my interpretation of how Union should work is not right here...

Comment: @wolfblade87 You should rather define `_fields_ = [('x_int', c_int), ('x_float', c_float), ...]`. Then you can set either the integer version or the float version. If you automatically want to decide which version to be used then you probably need a wrapper to handle that.

Comment: A `ctypes.Union` works like a union in C/C++. It allows to interpret a byte block in two or more different ways but it doesn't hold an information which interpretation is right (nor does it automatic type conversion) so the type information must be added somewhere outside.